# get list equal height inside div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please take a look at this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3sfy/3865/). I have two pairs of unordered lists, each of which is inside a div element`.pricing-table`. The following code can find the `li` with the same classes, get the max height and set the height of all of them to the same. But I want to limit it to getting the max-height of each pair of lists inside each div element.

I think this line is giving me problem because it is getting all the lists with the same classes in the document:

```
var elems   = $('.pricing-table ul li.' + elem.className),
```

I don't think I can use $(this) and update it like $(this +elem.className). Any suggestions?

Jquery script:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.pricing-table ul li').each(function(i, elem) {
        var elems   = $('.pricing-table ul li.' + elem.className),
            heights = $.map(elems, function(li) {
                return $(li).height();
            }),
            max     = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

        elems.height(max);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="pricing-table">
                <ul>
                    <li class="heading">Bronze</li>
                    <li class="year">2003<p>(Text)..........</li>
                    <li class="package">Starter package</li>
                    <li class="location">Africa (Text).......)</li>
                    <li class="description">Text............ </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="feature">
                    <li class="heading">Silver</li>
                    <li class="year">2004</li>
                    <li class="package">Intermediate package</li>
                    <li class="location">Asia</li>
                    <li class="description">Text............ </li>
                </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="pricing-table">
                <ul>
                    <li class="heading">Bronze</li>
                    <li class="year">2003<p>(Text)..........</li>
                    <li class="package">Starter package</li>
                    <li class="location">Africa (Text).......)</li>
                    <li class="description">Text............ </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="feature">
                    <li class="heading">Silver</li>
                    <li class="year">2004</li>
                    <li class="package">Intermediate package</li>
                    <li class="location">Asia</li>
                    <li class="description">Text............ </li>
                </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/p3sfy/3868/

Comment: @adeneo: Ah, using `ul:first` is nice, that should avoid going over the `li` multiple times like my lazy fix does. And also using the `each` element reference (`p_table`) to limit selection directly instead of using `.find` is a nice(r) touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’d need to get only the `li` that are descendants of your *current* `.pricing-table` element, so you’ll have to iterate over the latter first:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pricing-table').each(function (i, e) {
        $(e).find('ul li').each(function (i, elem) {
            var elems = $(e).find('ul li.' + elem.className),
                heights = $.map(elems, function (li) {
                    return $(li).height();
                }),
                max = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

            elems.height(max);
        });
    });
});
```

… or something like that. http://jsfiddle.net/p3sfy/3867/

(Still kinda ugly, since it will iterate over the `li` multiple times, so that’s rather just a “quick fix” – but I don’t wanna think about anything more sophisticated here before I have not first heard a *convincing* argument why this data is not marked up using *tables* in the first place …?)